# Why electromagnetic waves used in 5G can transfer more data per second than the old generations?

Tags: electromagnetism, frequency

My question is about frequency modulation used in telecommunication. Is the data transfer per time proportional to the frequency of the electromagnetic waves used? We know all electromagnetic waves travel at the speed of light in the vacuum, but what about changing the frequencies from one generation to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The radio waves used in wireless technologies carry signals by being *modulated* so the data signals are superimposed on the underlying *carrier frequency*. Generally speaking, the higher the carrier frequency is, the more data bits per second can be transmitted by it. This means that as wireless technology generations move to supporting higher and ever-higher *data rates*, the carrier frequencies must be moved to higher bands in the radio frequency spectrum.

This answer is a simplification of the larger picture involved. The wireless communication field is the subject of four-year engineering degrees and huge amounts of technical literature exist on it.